# UPI Deeplink Request failing

Tags: android, kotlin, upi

I have written this code for accepting payments through UPI apps installed on user's phone. Everything seems fine until user tries to make the payment it fails in weird ways.

> Google Pay -> "You have exceeded maximum transaction amount set by
> your bank".  
> Also Google Pay -> "Oops something went wrong". 
>  Phonepe ->
> " Could not initiate transaction. Please try again.."

I did try searching on internet but couldn't find anything.

```
private fun payWithUPI() {
        val uri: Uri = Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("upi")
            .authority("pay")
            .appendQueryParameter("pa", "my_vpa")
            .appendQueryParameter("pn", "name")
            .appendQueryParameter("mc", "merchant_id")
            .appendQueryParameter("tr", "123456789")
            .appendQueryParameter("am", "5.00")
            .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
            .build()

        val upiPayIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        upiPayIntent.data = uri
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with")
        if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
            startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "No UPI app found, please install one to continue",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
```

PS : I have registered as a merchant in bhim sbi and using that vpa.

Comment: same here if you find any solution please update here